# using wix tool to create the directory structure again with all data

Tags: directory, wix, windows-installer, directory-structure, heat

I executed the following command on CommandPrompt to copy the directory structure of one of the directories of my system:-

```
heat "I:\FOLDERNAME" --gg -sfrag -out "I:\directorystructure.wxs"
```

This command creates a .wxs file which has the directory structure same as my system's folder.
Now, i want to use some Wix Tool and i want to create the directory structure again USING THIS "directorystructure.wxs" file and get back all the data also.

Its like extracting data from a zip file which comes in the same directory structure as inside zip file.
(Here, i see directorystructure.wxs as the zip file)

If someone know how to implement it, please help.
Totally new approach is also fine(should be using wix tools).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _and get back all the data also_ ... a WXS file doesn't store any file data, but just pathes to the files.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure out how to do this?